# how to receive large data from a broadcast server using python sockets

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I need to receive real time data from a broadcast server and when doing so,  some parts of the data is missing while processing it. Here is the code which I've tried:

```
import socket
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient

def process():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Connect the socket
    server_address = ('ip', port)
    print('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
    sock.connect(server_address)

    try:
        # Look for the response

        while True:
              data = sock.recv(16384000)
              #print(data)
              if not data:
                 pass
              else:
                  print data
    except socket.error, ex:
        print('closing socket')
        sock.close()
        time.sleep(1)
        process()
        #def fun(data):
        #print data[0]
```

I do not understand how to verify if I've received the complete data without any data loss. Please help me to solve this issue. I am very new to python socket programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The receive calls normally return any data available, up to the requested amount, rather than waiting for receipt of the full amount requested. If you want to make sure you receive exactly `16384000` bytes of data, you have to implement it yourself. [TCP doesn't preserve message boundaries](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html). So you actually want something like this:

```
def recvall(sock, length):
    data = b''
    while length:
        recved = sock.recv(length)
        data += recved
        length -= len(recved)
    return data
```

Please note that this code hasn't been tested; it is also not an option for nonblocking sockets.